# Creating a radius around a singular lat/lon co-ordinate to create "arrival zone" so script knows when vehicle arrives at location

Tags: javascript, postgresql, google-maps, gps

It's 7am and I've been up for hours figuring this out, so forgive me if I'm not explaining this properly, but here it goes:

I'm working on a project which stores a list of locations (lat/lon) in a database, which then populates said locations on gmaps. Now what I'm trying to do is trigger a function when a vehicle which is being GPS tracked arrives at the location. Problem is, due to the nature of GPS the location may be off by a couple meters and might not trigger the function whatsoever. How would I go about creating a radius around the locations to act as a sort of "margin of error," or "buffer" that once entered by the tracked vehicles, it will trigger the function?

I'm storing the locations and gps cordinates as strings via postgres, and doing the queries with js. I know I'm likely forgetting some important info you guys could likely use to help, but as mentioned I'm super tired, so I guess any help on how to ask this question properly is also welcomed!

Comment: Do you need to know if it is close to 1 destination or to any of the destinations on the map?

Comment: Any of the destinations - there is more than one destination per vehicle being tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the inner working of google maps I would do something like this (it will be probably be not that fast if you have alot of destinations...)

```
var location = getGpsLocation();
//fill this array with your fetched destinations
var destinations = [{lat:34.356,lng:3.456},....];
//the amount of meters within a destination that is considered "arriving"
var arrivalRadius = 10;
var arrived = false;
destinations.forEach(function(destination){
    var distanceToLocation = calculateDistance(location, destination);
    if(distanceToLocation - arrivalRadius <= 0){
        arrived = true;
    }
});
```

To calculate the distance between 2 points (lat/lng) you can use the [haversine](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) method.

You will need to repeat this everytime your location changes, that why I said it will take a lot of time if you use alot of destinations.